# How to loop over two arraylist of different size in kotlin?

Tags: loops, kotlin, arraylist

I'm trying to get the value of multiple prices from a firestore database stored in arraylists and sum them to get a total price. The thing is that they are not the same size and I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

```
while (name1.count() > i) {
  try {
    priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + ":\n" + name1[i] + price1[contador] + "$\n"
    totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (hotels[i] * days).toString() + "$\n"
    while (name2.count() > j) {
      priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + name2[j] + price2[j] + "&\n"
      totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (Restaurants[j] * days).toString() + " Euros\n"
      j++
    }
    i++
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.i(TAG, e.toString())
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple things but it didn't work out. Something like this:

```
if (name1.count() > name2.count()) {
  while (name1.count() > i) {
    try {
      priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + ":\n" + name1[i] + price1[contador] + "$\n"
      totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (hotels[i] * days).toString() + "$\n"
      while (name2.count() > j) {
        priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + name2[j] + price2[j] + "&\n"
        totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (Restaurants[j] * days).toString() + " Euros\n"
        j++
      }
      i++
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.i(TAG, e.toString())
    }
  }
} else if (name2.count() > name1.count()) {
  while (name2.count() > i) {
    try {
      priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + ":\n" + name1[i] + price1[contador] + "$\n"
      totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (hotels[i] * days).toString() + "$\n"
      while (name2.count() > j) {
        priceBreakdown += "option " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + name2[j] + price2[j] + "&\n"
        totalPrice += "price " + (i + 1).toString() + "=>\n" + (Restaurants[j] * days).toString() + " Euros\n"
        j++
      }
      i++
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      Log.i(TAG, e.toString())
    }
  }
}
```

But it gave me the same error.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. Also, what are the "multiple things" you tried and why didn't they "work out"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: im new to programing, so i dont know much things, i tried first doing it with only one loop but it didnt work out, i also tried doing an if else and give two options wether which of the arrays was bigger but didnt work out either

Comment: Don't _describe_ what you have done - update your question to _show_ what you have tried. Also, your formatting is still not very good. The braces and indents are all off which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is almost completely incomprehensible because of the random indentation and the all the variables where we don't know the types. I don't think anyone will be able to help until you fix that. You can go to Code -> Reformat Code in your IDE to fix indentation automatically. It would also really help make it more concise if you used String templates instead of all the `.toString()` calls and concatenation.

Comment: If you want to sum the contents of two differently sized collections, why don't you just do each one separately and then add the two sums?

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually loop over collections like this, it's against the whole idea of functional programming in Kotlin, which has built in support for doing exactly what you need.

For example if you have two collections of ints, you could do this:

```
val total = collectionOne.sum() + collectionTwo.sum()
```

Or if you have two collections of a complex class that has the property amount on it, you can use sumOf :

```
val total = collectionOne.sumOf{it.amount} + collectionTwo.sumOf{it.amount}
```

As a general rule of thumb in Kotlin, if you are using a var as a total and then looping through a collection manually, you are probably doing it wrong and can use a built in collection function instead.